# How can I display JSON data using PHP

Tags: php, json

I have already created a dynamic JSON file.

My code is:

```
$res = mysql_query("select * from tbl_product where category='saree'");
while($rowpro=mysql_fetch_array($respro)) {
  $records []= $rowpro;
  $json_string=file_put_contents("product_file.json",json_encode($records));
}
```

How can I get data from the JSON file? Using a while loop or anything similar?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$res = mysql_query("select * from tbl_product where category='saree'");
      while($rowpro=mysql_fetch_array($res))
           {
               $records []= $rowpro;
                  $json_string=file_put_contents("product_file.json",json_encode($records));
           }
```

First, you have mistake on line 2

```
mysql_fetch_array($res)
```

AND NOT

```
mysql_fetch_array($respro)
```

Second, Use file_get_contents and json_decode functions

```
$file=file_get_contents('php://input');
$obj = json_decode($file, true);

$param = $obj['param'];
```

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

This is how you see the posted json data in your php file.

I would  prefer that:

```
   $json_string=json_encode($records);
```

you must put the header

```
header('Content-Type: application/json;charset=utf-8');
```

and other side

```
$file=file_get_contents('php://input');
$obj = json_decode($file, true);

$param = $obj['param'];
```

Answer (score 0):

First of all the way you are writing to the file inside the `while` loop is wrong.. Because you are unneccesarily calling the `file_put_contents()` again and again which is simply degrading your code performance..

So rewrite your code to this..

```
$res = mysql_query("select * from tbl_product where category='saree'");
while($rowpro=mysql_fetch_array($respro))
{
    $records[]= $rowpro;    
}
file_put_contents("product_file.json",json_encode($records));
```

---

To read the JSON data , make use of `file_get_contents()`

Like this..

```
$jsonData = file_get_contents("product_file.json");
echo $jsonData; //<--- Prints your JSON
```

Answer (score 0):

In PHP  ,

```
header('Content-Type: application/json;charset=utf-8');
$str = file_get_contents('product_file.json');
$jsonData = json_decode($str, true); //json decode
```

And in jquery you can use `jQuery.getJSON` example ,

```
 $.getJSON( "product_file.json", function( data ) {
 var items = [];
 $.each( data, function( key, val ) {
  items.push( "<li id='" + key + "'>" + val + "</li>" );
 });

 $( "<ul/>", {
   "class": "my-new-list",
     html: items.join( "" )
   }).appendTo( "body" );
 });
```